# Terraform - error while configuring s3 backend, with instance profile

Tags: terraform, amazon-linux-2

First up, we use ADFS and do not have individual IAM user profiles. We use the instance profiles as per the roles/permissions we need, and do not use individual access keys etc.,

This issue came up after i reinstalled TF with latest version. Didn't have this issue with the version installed about 3 weeks ago (dont know the version number as I reinstalled the new version now). I saw many posts about s3 backend creds but most of them talk about configuring individual access keys/profile, any idea how to resolve this while using instance profiles?

Error: No valid credential sources found │
Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, http response error StatusCode: 403, │ request to EC2 IMDS failed

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.19.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "tf-insights-state"
    key    = "dev-al2/tf-state"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}
```

In the RHEL vm, this is what I see on s3 backend:

```
$ cat ./.terraform/terraform.tfstate
{
    "version": 3,
    "serial": 2,
    "lineage": "xx-xx-xx-xxxxxxxx-xxx",
    "backend": {
        "type": "s3",
        "config": {
            "access_key": null,
            "acl": null,
            "assume_role_duration_seconds": null,
            "assume_role_policy": null,
            "assume_role_policy_arns": null,
            "assume_role_tags": null,
            "assume_role_transitive_tag_keys": null,
            "bucket": "tf-insights-state",
            "dynamodb_endpoint": null,
            "dynamodb_table": null,
            "encrypt": null,
            "endpoint": null,
            "external_id": null,
            "force_path_style": null,
            "iam_endpoint": null,
            "key": "dev/tf-state",
            "kms_key_id": null,
            "max_retries": null,
            "profile": null,
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "role_arn": null,
            "secret_key": null,
            "session_name": null,
            "shared_credentials_file": null,
            "skip_credentials_validation": null,
            "skip_metadata_api_check": null,
            "skip_region_validation": null,
            "sse_customer_key": null,
            "sts_endpoint": null,
            "token": null,
            "workspace_key_prefix": null
        },
        "hash": 2122242438
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "path": [
                "root"
            ],
            "outputs": {},
            "resources": {},
            "depends_on": []
        }
    ]
}
```